# Reload page with $route in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I've built a login module using Angular JS. After all validation and database checks have been made using $http, if the login is successful, the page needs to reload so the PHP can show the correct content to the user.

I've tried using $route to reload the page, but I just get weird errors like

```
Error: [$injector:unpr]....
```

Relevant code:

```
(function(){
  var app = angular.module('login',[]);

  app.controller('LoginController', function($scope,$http,$route){   

    $scope.loginCheck = function(){       
      $http({
        method  : 'POST',
        data    : $.param($scope.login),
        url     : '/assets/includes/login.php?query=login',
        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } 
      }).success(function(data){   
        if (data == 'success') $route.reload();
      });
    };

  });

})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just do a hard refresh, you want to re-render the server page if I'm not mistaken, a plain old Javascript reload should do it: `location.reload();`.

Comment: Yeh I suppose I could just do that. I thought Angular had built in methods though. What's `$route` for then?

Comment: $route.reload() works by reloading that route, re-initializing the controller+view, I'm not sure what you get that error, but if I understand correctly (don't know much PHP) you want to display data that is originating from outside angular, so it's natural that reloading the route won't work, if I wanted to update a server side page (i.e. the page hosting my application), I would do it by doing a javascript refresh.